# programatically set proxy of IE for all users?

Tags: windows, registry, internet-explorer

Environment: windows xp.

If my ID is "SYSTEM", and want to programatically change the IE proxy setting for all users on the same machine, is it possible?

Thanks,
xin

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", "proxy server");
RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
RegKey.SetValue("ProxyOverride", "your domain", RegistryValueKind.String);
```